# Most use emoji in field SQL

Tags: postgresql

I have a table in postgreSQL with some text which can contains emoji, I want to find which emoji is the most used. How can I do that without have to count separately the number of text with each emoji.

Comment: Do you have a table with a field that contains the emojis, one emoji per row? If so do a join and count...

Comment: I do not have a table and I can't create one